# Ajax Form Begin is not going to http GET method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am trying to send the text box values in ajax form begin and show the corresponding partial view But the problem is it always going to the post method but i mension the httpmethod also in ajax form

My Code is

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UserMenuPermission", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "GridData" }))
    {
         <div>
                    @Html.Label("User Name")
                    <input type="text"  placeholder="User Name" style="color: black;height:30px;" name="Username"/>                            
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
         </div>
    }
```

This code can pass the information to UserMenuPermissionController POST method but i need to pass in GET Method Please Help Me Friends

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Whenever you submit that's always a post.

Comment: Thats i having in partial view and this form submit button it has to go in http get method controller

Comment: But i want it to get method for that what can i do

Comment: Hi Dinesh, the submit button is always going to post the page.
What is the scenario, and y u dont want to post.?

Comment: If you have any issue with Posting the form, I would suggest you to remove the Ajax.Begin form and handle the things with JQuery Ajax for button click event.

Comment: No actually i want a output as partial view in that datagrid div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Suggest that use jquery.ajax get method

```
//Change your search button like this
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="ajaxCall()" />
//in javascript
function ajaxCall()
{
 $.ajax({
  url: "ActionURL",
  type:"get", //send it through get method
  data:{} 
  success: function(response) {
    //response is your partialview html
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    //Do Something to handle error
  }
});

}
```

in controller

```
public ActionResult GetHtml( )
{
    return PartialView( "UserDetails");
}
```

Comment: Ya my get method is return partial view how i will do that can you please show me any example